# How to access submenu item under subheading group with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

[image]

I can't access the "library-test" submenu item (see screenshot). My guess is that it has to do with the fact that the item is grouped/offset from the other items in the menu with the "Symbols" heading.

I tried treating "Symbols" as its own menu item and that didn't work.

Has anyone run into this before? Thanks!

AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Sketch"
        set frontmost to true
        click menu item "Rectangle" of menu of menu item "library-test" of menu "Insert" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Error message in Script Editor:

```
"Can’t get menu item "library-test" of menu "Insert" of menu bar 1 of process "Sketch".
```

**Edit**: UI Browser Screen Reader tool suggests that the path is correct:

[image]

Comment: A menu item can be disabled, which is what it looks like they did for their group “Headings”.  The menu items under this heading are indented, so you might look for the items names to have a couple of leading spaces.

Comment: @red_menace that's a great insight. tried adding both leading tab and spaces and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's bad news: I just downloaded *Sketch* and had a play around with the menu hierarchy.  Your reference is correct, but it appears it's only valid for a short amount of time after the menu closes.  For whatever reason, *Sketch* seems to hot load particular menu items on the fly, and unload them again when the menu is closed.

I obviously don't have your exist menu combinations, because I don't have those particular symbols, but here's one that you're probably familiar with:

```
menu item "Document" of menu "Insert" of menu bar item "Insert" of menu bar 1 of process "Sketch"
```

I had the menu open initially, and then closed it to go into *Script Editor* and bash out that `menu item` reference.  It worked fine, and I got a bunch of properties and attribute names for it:

```
{UIProperties:{minimum value:missing value ¬
    , orientation:missing value, position:{195, 264} ¬
    , class:menu item, accessibility description:missing value ¬
    , role description:"menu item", focused:missing value ¬
    , title:"Document", size:{173, 19}, help:missing value ¬
    , entire contents:{}, enabled:true, maximum value:missing value ¬
    , role:"AXMenuItem", value:missing value, subrole:missing value ¬
    , selected:true, name:"Document", description:"menu item"} ¬
    , UIAttributes:{"AXEnabled", "AXFrame", "AXParent", "AXChildren", ¬
    "AXSize", "AXMenuItemCmdGlyph", "AXRole", "AXMenuItemPrimaryUIElement", ¬
    "AXServesAsTitleForUIElements", "AXMenuItemCmdModifiers", "AXPosition", ¬
    "AXTitle", "AXHelp", "AXMenuItemCmdChar", "AXRoleDescription", ¬
    "AXSelected", "AXMenuItemCmdVirtualKey", "AXMenuItemMarkChar"} ¬
    , UIActions:{"AXCancel", "AXPress"}}
```

About 20-30 seconds later, the exact same `menu item` reference threw an error, reporting that `menu item "Document"` wasn't found. So I ran this:

```
name of menu items of menu "Insert" of menu bar item "Insert" of menu bar 1 of process "Sketch"
```

You can probably infer that this will return the names of all the `menu items` within the `"Insert"` menu, and one would expect `"Document"` to be in there:

```
{"New Page", missing value, "Shape", "Vector", "Pencil", missing value, "Text", ¬
 "Image…", missing value, "Artboard", "Slice", "Hotspot", missing value, missing value}
```

Nope.  For comparison, here's what the menu looks like on screen:

[image]

The `missing value` items are fine—they correspond to a horizontal divider, except the last one, which corresponds to the `"Symbol"` sub-section header. What's curious is that the list terminates there; there's not even a placeholder for the additional menu items that *literally* do not exist an anymore (until I open the menu back up again).

I would guess that the only way to get access to menu items like that is to have your script click the menu to open it up, then click the menu item, and so on... Very inelegant, and I personally would rather throw my computer into the sun than do that, but I don't see another option here.

The application is *apparently* scriptable, but it doesn't come with a terminology dictionary, so there's not a lot we can do there, either.

Comment: Yep, this is it! Thanks so much for downloading Sketch and investigating. I tried your suggestion about clicking the menu first and interestingly I can get the script to find the "Rectangle" item (via get items) but it won't receive the click command. It returns "missing value". Sketch has a plugin API so I'm going to try that instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have found some apps (like Safari) will work if you click the top-level menu, then `delay 0.1` and then click the real item you want. This will force the menu to be created and event handlers to be attached. This works well for web content also.

Comment: @JoeSteele I covered that as one potential option, which I described throwing my computer into the sun as a more appealing option back then, and I can't say I've changed my mind about that, personally.  It's obviously down to individual preferences.  Anyway, _Sketch_ is different to most other applications, in that it went to the trouble of actively _unloading_ its menu items a few seconds after they close. There's no need to click the top-level menu in _Safari_ as all menu items are accessible provided _Safari_ is frontmost. Also, you should use JavaScript for interacting with web content.

Comment: @CJK Re. "all menu items are accessible in Safari provides Safari is topmost". This maybe true (I have not verified) for all the main application menu items. I suspect it is not for service workers. However it is definitely not true for menus on the developers console. Those seem to behave more like web content. I would _guess_ in this case it is because that menu bar is populated dynamically depending on what content  is in the log. I would like to use Javascript, but I have not found it to be helpful for interacting with things in the developer console.

Comment: I should add that your answer is still the best one to this question -- don't let my nit-picking detract from that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A peculiarity of AppleScript GUI scripting is that elements of objects are always a to-many relationship, even when we might naturally presume a to-one relationship. You and I know that a menu item can only have one menu attached to it, but AppleScript doesn't, so we still have to specify an index for the menu. Things should work correctly if you write:

```
click menu item "Rectangle" of menu 1 of menu item "library-test" [...]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before posting the question but it doesn't solve it. The problem is a node higher, that the script can't find "library-test".

Answer (score 0):

There may be some strange character in the menu name, such as a soft hyphen, non-breaking hyphen, non-breaking space, etc.  One solution would be to try to get the particular menu item by its index, whatever the name is.  A handler to do that would be something like:

```
on run -- example
    clickMenu at {"Sketch", "Insert", 18, "Rectangle"}
end run

to clickMenu at menuList -- {application, menu, menu/item/index, menu/item/index, ...}
    try
        set itemCount to (count menuList)
        if itemCount < 3 then error "clickMenu handler:  menu item list contains too few items"
        set {appName, menuName} to items 1 thru 2 of menuList
        set {menuItem, found} to {last item of menuList, false}
        tell application appName to activate
        tell application "System Events" -- set up the menu path
            set appName to (name of application processes whose frontmost is true) as text -- process name might be different
            set menuPath to menu menuName of menu bar item menuName of menu bar 1 of application process appName
            if itemCount > 3 then repeat with i from 3 to (itemCount - 1) -- add sub menu items
                set menuName to item i of menuList
                if class of menuName is integer then set menuName to item menuName of (get name of menu items of menuPath)
                set menuPath to menu menuName of menu item menuName of menuPath
            end repeat
            if class of menuItem is not integer then -- go for a a partial name match of the last item
                repeat with anItem in (get name of menu items of menuPath)
                    if anItem begins with menuItem then -- can also use 'contains', etc
                        set {menuItem, found} to {anItem, true}
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                end repeat
                if not found then error "clickMenu handler:  menu item " & quoted form of menuItem & " not found"
            end if
            if (enabled of menu item menuItem of menuPath) then -- or filter for other desired property
                click menu item menuItem of menuPath
                delay 0.5
                return true -- success
            end if
            return false -- menu item not clicked
        end tell
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
        -- error errorMessage number errorNumber -- uncomment to pass error up the chain
        log errorMessage
        return false
    end try
end clickMenu
```